# Module chaining in NGINX

Tags: c, nginx, module, chaining

I'm writing a NGINX module in C that requires access to Redis.

To make those calls non-blocking, I want to use asynchronous access to it (either with official C API for Redis or using [redis2-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module)).

I've read [Emiller's Guide](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html) and it seems to me that I need to build a "chain" of modules. Something like:

My module parses HTTP request, makes corresponding request to the other module, that works with Redis asynchrounously, as "upstream"(?)

On the Redis response, the control is being returned to my module and it finalizes HTTP response, sending data back to server.

What I don't get is how to implement those chains? I hardly can find the good example, all builtin NGINX modules seem to redirect control to itself (u = r->upstream;) ? Any way to specify other module as an upstream?

Appreciate your help with a good code example of chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to partially implement the logic using LUA interface (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule + https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis).

It basically works in non-blocking way using nginx subrequests but provides much easier way to write the module.
Part of the logic (handler-based) I implemented using C modules.